# How do you use onChange in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What is the difference between these methods on handling input changes and when should i use one or the other?:

```js
const handleChange = () => {
  console.log("hello")
}

// first method
<input
  onChange={() => handleChange()}
  [...]

// second method
<input
  onChange={() => handleChange}
  [...]

// third method
<input
  onChange={handleChange}
  [...]

// fourth method
<input
  onChange={handleChange()}
  [...]
```

Note that I'm using functional components.

Comment: 3rd method. onchange takes a function and passes the event as an argument to the function. Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Why are you tagging + titling this as related to react hooks?

Comment: So i dont get answers that is related to class components - just like you linked me. In class components you bind the method in the constructor but there is no constructor in functional components.

Comment: Binding the method is unrelated to your question + you can use functional components without hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Use of functions depend on requirement.

**First** is used when you need to pass something like - **event**, **data** for some operation.

**Second** way isn't correct way.

**Third** way is recommended to use

```
<input
  onChange={handleChange} />
```

> **Fourth** way isn't recommended to use because it will call on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is the kost correct, except you need the default onChange's arg, which is a native event, so for example: `(e) => { e.preventDefault() }`. With this method you can assign a function's execution with some non-default args.

The second one is totally incorrect.

The third one would call our function with the default argument(s), so here it's the same as my corrected method one.

The fouth one is also incorrect, as it would execute your function at the moment of React binding it to the element.

Answer (score 0):

> first method <input   onChange={() => handleChange()} [...]

> second method <input onChange={() => handleChange} [...]

> fourth method <input onChange={handleChange()} [...]

These all do not use anywhere as per ECMA 6.

if we have only one onChange event which is your third option then we have to just pass our event as a name no need to pass the event object to in the argument as a parameter.

```
// third method 
<input onChange={handleChange} [...]
```

but, if we need to pass our event as a argument then go for this option as per below[we have more than one event onClick or onchange]:

`e.g. <input   onChange={(event) => handleChange(event); otherEvent(); }}`

and then we can access our handle change value using this method

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log("hello", event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, onChange handover change event as a parameter of onChangeHandler.

First Method is used to use custom parameters:
`onChange={() => handleChange(customParam1, customParam2)}`:

The second method is used to return the handle change function whenever an onChange event occurs.
`onChange={() => handleChange}` equals to `onChange={function handleChange(e){[...]}}`

Third method is used to use default onChange event as parameter of handleChange function:
`onChange={handleChange}` equals to `onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}`

The last method is used to use return value of handleChange as onChangeHandler:
`onChange={handleChange()}` equals to `onChange={(e) => handleChange()(e)}`

The 2nd and 4th are similar as they use the return value as onChange handler.

Btw, 2nd method is the best one for onChange handling.
You should use the 2nd method as your primary method.
Thank you.